# How to delete books from iBooks on iOS 10?

Tags: iphone, books

I want to delete some iBooks from purchased off my iBooks app, but the previous solution of hovering above it and an "x" appearing over it isn't working. I have an iPhone 7 with iOS 10.3.2

Answer (score 1):

To delete books in the iOS 10 iBooks app:

- Tap "Select" in the top right.
- Tap on the books you wish to delete (in the list view, you can also tap the checkboxes).
- Tap the "Delete" button in the top left.

You can re-download deleted books from the "Purchased" tab.

Answer (score 1):

If I open iBooks on my iPhone I can get a listing of my books. At the top of page there is a 'select' button. If I select a book, the top menu changes to 'view move delete'. The delete option will remove the book.